# A matrix identity related to the Kalman filter

Tags: matrices, kalman-filter

I am trying to rederive the formula that relates the covariant matrices of successive iterations in the Kalman filter. I can quite easily show that the covariant matrix post-update $Y \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ satisfies
$$
Y^{-1} = (X^{-1} + H^T R^{-1} H),
$$
where $X \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ the covariance matrix pre-update, $R \in \mathbb R^{m\times m} $ is the covariance matrix of the observational noise and $H \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ is the observation model.
On Wikipedia, the formula given for $Y$ is instead
$$
Y = (I - X H^T(R + HXH^T)^{-1}H)X.
$$
The fact that these represent quantities related to the Kalman filter is not important; the two formulae give the same value for $Y$ for any $X$, $R$ symmetric and positive definite and any $H$ with the appropriate dimension.

If $n = m$ and $H$ is invertible, it is quite easy to see that the two definitions coincide.
Indeed, denoting by $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ the matrices obtained by the first and second formula, respectively,
\begin{align}
    Y_1^{-1} Y_2 &= (X^{-1} + H^T R^{-1} H)(I - X H^T(R + HXH^T)^{-1} H)X \\
                 &= (X^{-1} + H^T R^{-1} H)((I - X H^T(H(H^{-1}R H^{-T} + X) H^T)^{-1} H)X \\
                 &= (X^{-1} + H^T R^{-1} H)((I - X H^T H^{-T} (H^{-1}R H^{-T} + X)^{-1} H^{-1} H)X \\
                 &= (X^{-1} + H^T R^{-1} H)(H^{-1} R H^{-T} + X - X) (H^{-1}R H^{-T} + X)^{-1}X \\
                 &= X^{-1} (I + X H^T R^{-1} H)(H^{-1} R H^{-T}) (H^{-1}R H^{-T} + X)^{-1}X \\
                 &= X^{-1} (H^{-1} R H^{-T} + X) (H^{-1}R H^{-T} + X)^{-1}X \\
                 &= X^{-1} X = I. \\
\end{align}
However, the proof for general $H$ still eludes me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having to worry about maybe making mistakes in your calculates, one can also show that they are equivalent by using the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity)

$$
\left(A + U\,C\,V\right)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1} U \left(C^{-1} + V A^{-1} U\right)^{-1} V\,A^{-1}.
$$

Applying this to the inverse of your first equation yields $A=X^{-1}\!$, $U=H^\top\!$, $C=R^{-1}$ and $V=H$, so

$$
Y = (X^{-1} + H^\top R^{-1} H)^{-1} = X - X\,H^\top \left(R + H\,X\,H^\top\right)^{-1} H\,X.
$$

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that identity.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was just a matter of doing the calculation carefully.
\begin{align}
    Y_1^{-1} Y_2 &= (X^{-1} + H^T R^{-1} H)(I - X H^T(R + HXH^T)^{-1} H)X \\
     &= (X^{-1} + H^T R^{-1} H)(I - X H^T(R + HXH^T)^{-1} H)X \\
     &= I + H^T R^{-1} H X - (H^T + H^T R^{-1} H X H^T) (R + H X H^T)^{-1} H X \\
     &= I + H^T R^{-1} H X - H^T R^{-1}(H + H X H^T) (R + H X H^T)^{-1} H X \\
     &= I + H^T R^{-1} H X - H^T R^{-1} H X = I.
\end{align}